# Remove '<p>' from Rss Parser Text

Tags: objective-c, xml-parsing, rss

I create an RSS parser and it works very well, however, I have a problem with the 'p' element. My RSS encoded feeds have 'p' and when I take that text it comes with it. How can I remove it?

I want to remove this:

```
<p>
```

This is my parser:

```
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if ([current isEqualToString:@"item"]) [outstring appendFormat:@"%@", @"\n"];
    current = nil;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if (!current) return;
    if ([current isEqualToString:@"content:encoded"]) [outstring appendFormat:@"%@", string];
}
```

and this is my bottom action:

```
_kocTextView.text = @"";

        NSURL *url4 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.iburc.com/?feed=rss2&cat=7"];

        top10Parser = [[Top10Parser alloc] initWithDelegate: self url: url4];
```

Comment: Side issue: Why are you using `appendFormat` instead of `appendString`? Only use formats when you actually have string formats. Example: `[outstring appendString:@"\n"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
[stringWhereYouWantToRemoveP stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<p>" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if ([current isEqualToString:@"item"]) [outstring appendFormat:@"%@", @"\n"];
```

to:

```
if ([current isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
    [outstring replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"<p>" withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, outstring.length)];
    [outstring replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"</p>" withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, outstring.length)];

    [outstring appendString:@"\n"];
}
```

Depending on your needs you may wish to replace the `<p>` with `\n\n` instead of the empty string.

Comment: thanks for answer but same. its not fix, @rmaddy. its haven't got any error but nothing chance.

Comment: Where did you make these changes and where are you checking the result?

Comment: return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

Comment: What? What does `UIApplicationMain` have to do with my answer?